# I don't want my query to return a result if the subquery results are null

Tags: node.js, sqlite

My query (of a subquery) returns an object with all fields null when I query for a non-existent ID.  Ideally the result would be SQLite's normal empty array, as in typical instances where the query returns 0 rows.  I think the problem is that I am creating new columns in my subquery, and the outer query keeps those columns even though all their values are null.  Interestingly, if I insert 'COUNT(*)' in the outer query, the count shows 1 row: a row of null values for every column.  Apologies for the length of this query:

```
SELECT
  *,
  JSON_GROUP_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT(
    'American Indian',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN ROUND(american_indian * 1.0 / 
    num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'Asian',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN. ROUND(asian * 1.0 / num_allegations * 
    100.0, 2) END,
    'Black',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(black * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'Hispanic',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(hispanic * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'White',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(white * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'Other Ethnicity',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(other_ethnicity * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'Ethnicity Unknown',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(ethnicity_unknown * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END
    )) AS race_percentages,
  JSON_GROUP_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT(
    'Female',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(female * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'Male',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(male * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'Female (trans)',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(trans_female * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'Male (trans)',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(trans_male * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'Gender-nonconforming',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(gender_non_conforming * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END,
    'Unknown/refused',
    CASE WHEN num_allegations > 4 THEN
    ROUND(gender_unknown * 1.0 / num_allegations * 100.0, 2) END
    )) AS gender_percentages
    FROM (
      SELECT 
        cops.*,
        cmd_units.id as command_unit_id,
        CASE WHEN COUNT(allegations.id) > 9
          THEN (
            ROUND(COUNT(CASE WHEN allegations.board_disposition LIKE 'Substantiated%' THEN 1 END)*1.0 / COUNT(allegations.id) * 100.0, 2))
            END substantiated_percentage,
            COUNT(*) AS num_allegations,
            COUNT(CASE WHEN allegations.board_disposition LIKE 'Substantiated%' THEN 1 END) AS num_substantiated,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_ethnicity LIKE '%indian%' THEN allegations.id END) AS american_indian,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_ethnicity LIKE '%asian%' THEN allegations.id END) AS asian,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_ethnicity LIKE '%black%' THEN allegations.id END) AS black,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_ethnicity LIKE '%hispanic%' THEN allegations.id END) AS hispanic,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_ethnicity LIKE '%white%' THEN allegations.id END) AS white,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_ethnicity LIKE 'Other Race' THEN allegations.id END) AS other_ethnicity,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_ethnicity LIKE '' THEN allegations.id END) AS ethnicity_unknown,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_gender LIKE 'male%' THEN allegations.id END) AS male,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_gender LIKE '%female%' THEN allegations.id END) AS female,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_gender LIKE '%Gender non-conforming%' THEN allegations.id END) AS gender_non_conforming,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_gender LIKE '%Transman%' THEN allegations.id END) AS trans_male,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_gender LIKE '%Transwoman%' THEN allegations.id END) AS trans_female,
            COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN allegations.complainant_gender LIKE '' THEN allegations.id END) AS gender_unknown,
            COUNT(DISTINCT complaints.id) AS num_complaints
            FROM 
              cops 
            JOIN 
              allegations 
            ON 
              cops.id = allegations.cop
            JOIN
              complaints
            ON 
              complaints.id = allegations.complaint_id 
            JOIN
              command_units cmd_units
            ON
              cops.command_unit = cmd_units.unit_id
            WHERE
              cops.id = (?)
            )
          WHERE id IS NOT NULL
```

It returns this for a bad id:

```
{
id: null,
first_name: null,
last_name: null,
command_unit: null,
precinct: null,
shield_no: null,
rank_abbrev: null,
rank_full: null,
ethnicity: null,
gender: null,
command_unit_full: null,
command_unit_id: null,
substantiated_percentage: null,
num_allegations: 0,
num_substantiated: 0,
american_indian: 0,
asian: 0,
black: 0,
hispanic: 0,
white: 0,
other_ethnicity: 0,
ethnicity_unknown: 0,
male: 0,
female: 0,
gender_non_conforming: 0,
trans_male: 0,
trans_female: 0,
gender_unknown: 0,
num_complaints: 0,
race_percentages: {
American Indian: null,
Asian: null,
Black: null,
Hispanic: null,
White: null,
Other Ethnicity: null,
Ethnicity Unknown: null
},
gender_percentages: {
Female: null,
Male: null,
Female (trans): null,
Male (trans): null,
Gender-nonconforming: null,
Unknown/refused: null
}
}
```

Comment: This does look like an expensive query. Why not quickly verify whether the id is valid first and then run this query (if it is)?